# How to hide a Navigation Bar?

Tags: sencha-touch, hide, sencha-touch-2, navigationbar

How to hide a Navigation Bar in Sencha Touch 2

Answer (score 3):

Try passing

```
navigationBar: false
```

to the `navigationview` config, when you create it. I assume you are using a `navigationview`